# Java: How do I check if an element in an array has been initialized?

Tags: java

I want to check if a certain element in an array has been initilized, how can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All values in an array are initialised when the array is created.

Initial values may be set explicitly (e.g. `X[] xs = {x1, ..., xN};`), or default values will be assigned when the array is instantiated.

For an array of objects, the default value of each element will be `null`; for a `boolean` array, the value will be `false`; for an array of `byte`, `char`, `int`, `long` the value will be `0` and for an array of `float` or `double` the value will be `0.0`.

Comment: note: All the values could have been initilised to the default.  You can only determine if an array has been initalised, but you cannot determine an array has not been initialised.

Comment: thanks @peter - think I get what you mean.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can check whether it's been set to not have the default value, e.g.

```
String[] array = getArrayFromSomewhere();
if (array[10] != null)
{
    ...
}
```

(For primitive types you'd use `0`, `'\0'`, `false` etc.)

However, that's not the same not being initialized. It could have been set to null after having been set to a different value.

Arrays keep no record of whether an element has been specifically set - the elements are all initialized to the default value, and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] X; // X has not been initialized

try {
    System.out.println(""+X.length); // This will crash if X is not initialized
} catch (NullPointerException e) { // X is empty
    System.out.println("X has not been initialized.");
    // Do whatever you want here with X
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of already approved answer, you can verify with [java9+](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-465BA4F5-E77D-456F-BCB7-D826AC1E18AE) in jshell as it tells you the default index values.

primitive arrays

```
jshell> byte[] data = new byte[10]
data ==> byte[10] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }

jshell> int[] data = new int[10]
data ==> int[10] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }

jshell> char[] data = new char[10]
data ==> char[10] { '\000', '\000', '\000', '\000', '\000' ... , '\000', '\000', '\000' }

jshell> boolean[] data = new boolean[10]
data ==> boolean[10] { false, false, false, false, false,  ... lse, false, false, false }
```

object arrays

```
jshell> String[] data = new String[10]
data ==> String[10] { null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null }
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply way of checking is:

```
int[] ar = new int[10];

if (ar.length < 0) {
    System.out.println("Not initialized ");
} else {
    System.out.println("Initialized");
}
```

Comment: This is so wrong.  The length of an array in Java can never be negative.

Comment: @Stephen - Mohamed is **correct**, the algorithm always gives the correct answer (OK, because every array is always initialized with default values, the first check is not necessary, but nevertheless - the algorithm will pass **every** test!) ;-)