# Is there a way to check if an array is using a default or assigned value?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to java and I'm wanting to create an array and change specific values in the array. I know that if I initialize an array like so:

```
int[] myArray = new int[4];
```

all values in the array will be set to 0. If I want to check to see if the 0 value was intentionally is there anything, such as a reference, that will be different than the default value that would indicate that the value of 0 was not set by default?

Comment: There is only one sort of "zero". You can't tell if that was set explicitly or not, other than by analyzing the code.

Comment: No. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: No. I can only imagine why you would need something like this.

Comment: I want to do this so that I can make sure that I don't overwrite a value that was intentionally set.

Comment: Nope. You could always use the nullable `Integer` wrapper type, but there's nothing preventing actual code from assigning an array item as `null` programmatically anyway, so it's weak sauce.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How do I check if an element in an array has been initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212388/java-how-do-i-check-if-an-element-in-an-array-has-been-initialized)

Comment: I saw that and it's kind of similar but I'm wanting to know if an item in an array has been changed after it's been initialized.

Comment: You could create an equivalent `boolean[]`, and set it to true when the corresponding int value has been set.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use an array of `Integer` instead of `int`. Then you can distinguish unassigned values by comparing an item to `null` because the items are initialized by `null` instead of zero.

Comment: Please check Mena's comment above

Comment: @P.An Thank you. I checked it. But still I would use `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately fill the array with some value that is never possible to be set intentionally. For instance, if you know that legitimate values are between 0 and 40, you could do:

```
int[] myArray = new int[4];
Arrays.fill(myArray, 42);
```

Then later on you can tell if an element has been set by testing if it's 42.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the default value to other than `0` by using looping

```
for( int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
        myArray[i]=1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own wrapper class around the array. This allows you to create another internal boolean array to keep track what value was modified:

```
public class Array {

    private final int[] values;
    private final boolean[] modified;

    public Array(int length) {
        values = new int[length];
        modified = new boolean[length];
    }

    public void set(int index, int value) {
        values[index] = value;
        modified[index] = true;
    }

    public int get(int index) {
        return values[index];
    }

    public boolean isDefaultValue(int index) {
        return !modified[index];
    }

}
```